# Erro no Laravel após inserir o método save()

Tags: php, laravel

Boa tarde
Estou tentdo a todo custo fazer um insert no banco, usando o Laravel e Controller, porém, não funciona de maneira nenhuma, já tentei de tudo quanto é forma, fazendo migrate, trocando nome de tela, enfim, de todas as maneiras e nada. No meu rote, tenho esse código:

```
Route::when('*', 'csrf', array('post'));
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getIndex');
Route::post('save', 'HomeController@postAddUser');
Route::post('login', 'HomeController@postLogin');
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
   Route::controller('profile', 'ProfilesController');
});
```

No meu Controller, tenho a seguinte action:

```
public function postInserir(){
    $posts = new Post();
    $posts->nome = Auth::user()->nome;
    $posts->post = Input::get('text_post');
    $posts->save();

    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

Model:

```
 class Post extends Eloquent{

 }
```

No meu banco, tenho uma tabela chamada posts com um id auto incremento not null, um campo chamado nome varchar 255 not null e um campo chamado post longtext

E esse aqui é a minha View:

```
<?php echo Form::open(array('action' => 'ProfilesController@postInserir', 'role' => 'form', 'id' => 'post-form')); ?>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <textarea id="text_post" name="text_post" class="form-control" rows="2"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer" style="background-color: black;">

            <button type="submit" id="publicar" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right">Publicar</button>
            <?php echo Form::close(); ?>
```

Se eu submeter o form, ele vai até a action, ele exibe o que foi passado e tudo mais, o problema e quando eu faço eu chamo o método $posts->save(), que me da Mensagem "Whoops, looks.."

Alguém sabe aonde pode estar o problema?

Answer (score 3):

Isso está acontecendo por que na sua tabela não tem criado as colunas created_at e updated_ad, para adicionar eles em sua tabela, no seu schema adicione a linha

```
$this->timestamps();
```

desse modo ele irá criar essas colunas.

Mas se você realmente não for usar por se tratar de uma tabela pivot etc, você pode dizer ao model que ao fazer alguma alteração e inserir, não ira popular essas colunas
para isso vai no model e adicione essa linha

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Pronto, é isso!

Comment: Caso sua resposta seja suficiente para solucionar o problema do autor, se possível, elabore melhor sua resposta.

Comment: Editei e expliquei mais detalhadamente